# HTML POST insert line break in parameters

Tags: java, html, post, line, newline

currently I am trying to use `hilite.me/api` to format Java code. It all works ok but the only problem is that `\n` line breaks seem to be ignored and the output is just one long line. Anyone know how I can properly pass in linebreaks into the POST request. Thanks.
The API is parameters are supposed to be as follows: `code=` the Java code to be inputted. `lexer=` language to format in (in this case Java)

My code:

```
public static final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0", HILITE_URL = "http://hilite.me/api";

public static String hilite(String lang, String code) throws Exception {
    URL obj = new URL(HILITE_URL);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

    String par = "&code=" + code.replaceAll("\n", "\r\n") + "&?lexer=" + lang;

    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
    dos.writeBytes(par);
    dos.flush();
    dos.close();

    int res = conn.getResponseCode();

    if(res == 200){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String in;
        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        while((in = read.readLine()) != null)
            sb.append(in + "\n");
        read.close();
        return sb.toString();
    }else{
        System.err.println("UNABLE TO CONNECT! WITH RES: " + res);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is an encoding error or what the default encoding method is for HttpURLConnection, but perhaps its not properly encoding the \n.

I believe the ASCII line feed is

```
%0A
```

Perhaps try using

```
URLEncoder.encode(code)
```

Comment: All of this seems to work decent by the output is not the same as the website shows...

Answer (score 0):

In first place, I'd suggest using a high-level library to call what most apparently is a RESTful WebService.  Jersey -the reference implementation of JAX-RS- should be enough.

Only if for some reason that this not possible, you need to determine what encodings are supported or assumed by the web service.  Apparently, in your case this is the default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.  Replace spaces by `+` characters and any character outside set `[0-9A-Za-z]` by its URL encoding (`%HH` with HH the hexadecimal ASCII numeric value).

Class `java.net.URLEncoder` will do this work for you and there is little excuse not to use it.